# Привязка контекста объекта к внутренним фунциям метода

Tags: javascript

У объекта есть метод, записанный в прототип:

```
ServisePlate.prototype.disclose = function() {
    console.log('запустилась функция disclose');
    function showBody() {
        if(this.elem.offsetHeight < (this.body.offsetHeight + this.initialSize)) {
            this.elem.style.height = this.elem.offsetHeight + this.settings.step + 'px';
            setTimeout(showBody.call(this), this.settings.speed);
        }
    }
    function hideBody() {
        if(this.elem.offsetHeight > this.initialSize) {
            this.elem.style.height = this.elem.offsetHeight - this.settings.step + 'px';
            setTimeout(hideBody.call(this), this.settings.speed);
        }else {
            this.elem.style.height = '';
        }
    }
    if(this.elem.offsetHeight == this.initialSize || this.elem.offsetHeight >= (this.body.offsetHeight + this.initialSize)) {
        if(this.elem.offsetHeight == this.initialSize) {
            console.log('Сработало условие 1');
            showBody.call(this);
        } else {
            console.log('Сработало условие 2')
            hideBody.call(this);
        }
   }
}
```

У него есть две внутренние функции `hideBody` и `showBody`.
Как правильно привязать к ним контекст объекта? Через `call(this)`, как в коде выше все функции запускаются и отрабатывают за исключением переменных объявленных в конструкторе - это объект:

```
this.settings = {
    step: 30,
    speed: 1000
}
```

его свойства задают шаг наращивания пикселей и таймаут повторного запуска.
Так вот функции отрабатываю так, словно их нет..... хотя из этих функций выводятся их значения через `console.log`.
По идее с такими значениями каждую секунду к свойству `height` должно прибавляться 30px, но нужная высота получается моментально, без плавного прибавления.
Через `apply` все происходит точно так же, а через `bind` вовсе не запускаются функции.
Как быть?

Comment: а почему эти функции просто в прототип не поместить? зачем придумывать себе сложности? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, Вы имеете ввиду прототип самого объекта? Хз, можно конечно и в прототип, но я думал правильнее будет если они будут внутренними функциями метода.... так сказать его реализацией...Ведь кроме этого метода они никому не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Налицо неверное использование технологии.

Самое просто решение: перенести эти функции в прототип объекта - нет нужды менять контекст, нет проблем с неправильным использованием *call*.

Конкретно в данном коде проблема заключается в том, что [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), первым параметром ожидает **функцию**. Применение же *call* - сразу вызывает функцию.

То есть, в данном случае надо было использовать *bind*

Еще один вариант избежать проблем со сменой контекста, использовать [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Например:

```
var showBody = ()=>{ 
    ...
    setTimeout(showBody, this.settings.speed)
}
```

Comment: Еще один вопрос: Имеет ли смысл удалять таймаут после того как функция закончила работу?

Comment: @pepel_xD, нет, если функция _уже_ выполнился, вызов на таймере _clearTimeout_ ничего не даст